# Invisible and unselectable text

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, boxes, transparency, height

For alignment reasons (for boxes that align themselves on the text they contain), I currently use this command :

```
\newcommand{\uplowtext}[1]{
    \transparent{0.}TJPtjp
    \transparent{1.}#1
    \transparent{0.}TJPtjp
}
```

to make all boxes with the same height by adding an invisible "TJPtjp" before and after the text. But the problem is when someone copy/paste the text from the pdf: he can see the "TJPtjp".

Instead of text, how to put one invisible "box" of the height of "TJPtjp" before and after the text, aligned as a text, so that it will act as a vertical spacer.

Comment: `\leavevmode\phantom{0.}`?

Comment: Can you explain a little more, what would be the whole replacement of my \newcommand?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LaTeX has an undocumented but very useful feature:

```
\phantom{text}
\hphantom{text}
\vphantom{text}
```

will create “phantoms”; they occupy the same space of `text`, but `\hphantom` just for the width (no height and depth) and `\vphantom` just for the height and depth (no width). In any case no character will appear, just the space they would occupy.

For TeXnical reasons, you should add `\leavevmode` before any of these commands (unless you are sure they will be used in LR-mode or math mode).

So what you want seems to be

```
\newcommand{\fake}[1]{\leavevmode\hphantom{#1}}
```

and `\fake{0.}` instead of `\transparent{0.)`. Your code would become

```
\newcommand{\fake}[1]{\leavevmode\hphantom{#1}}
\newcommand{\uplowtext}[1]{%
  \fake{0.}TJPtjp
  \fake{1.}#1
  \fake{0.}TJPtjp
}
```

Comment: Just curious, were you joking when you said that the `phantom` commands are undocumented?  In what sense are they undocumented?  For example, they are mentioned in "The LaTeX Companion".